# Perl script to take a screenshot of a web page and email it

Tags: perl

I was wondering if there is a way to take a screenshot of a web page and automatically email it using perl. Is there any cpan library for this purpose. I need some design suggestions/ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly with perl, no. Last time I checked (a fair while ago, admittedly) it is possible to drive [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) through perl (with [WWW::Selenium](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Selenium)), which when properly set up can start a browser and take a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way with Perl.
The easiest thing probably is to use phantomjs (a headless WebKit browser) to convert the page to PDF or JPEG and then mail the resulting file using one of the various email modules of Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) Perl module.

You need to have Firefox with [MozREPL plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozrepl/) installed.

An example of screenshot [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::Examples#Example:-screenshot.pl).